# getting the following error: undefined method `members_schools' for #<Member:0x0055c78d780190>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

i am getting the above error after trying to create a new member. 
I have many to many relationship between member and school, which called members_schools. Any help would be great! Thanks

```
<h1><%= @member.name %></h1>
  <h4><%= @member.email %></h4>
  <%= link_to 'Back to member index', members_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <ul>
    <% @member.members_schools.each do |member_school| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to member_school.school.name, school_path(member_school.school) %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Show us the Member class.

Answer (score 1):

In your member model define `has_and_belongs_to_many :schools` and in school.rb define vice versa as `has_and_belongs_to_many :members`

Now in the view file modify as

```
<% @member.schools.each do |school| %>
```

Things should work!!!!!